# selecting all elements of a class within elements of given id

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

My HTML code looks something like

```
<div id="partA">
    <div class="myClass typeA"> blabla </div>
    <div class="myClass typeA"> blabla </div>
    <div class="myClass typeA"> blabla </div>
    <div class="myClass typeB"> blabla </div>
</div>

<div id="partB">
    <div class="myClass typeA"> blabla </div>
    <div class="myClass typeA"> blabla </div>
    <div class="myClass typeA"> blabla </div>
    <div class="myClass typeB"> blabla </div>
</div>
```

I want to use javascript to count the number of elements of class `myClass`, but only the one that are within `#partA`.
When I use
`$(".myClass").size()`
I get `8` as result (it counts all the elements from both `partA` and `partB`).
When I use
`$(".myClass.typeA").size()`
I get `6` (it gets all `myClass` and `typeA` elements, from both parts)
But when I use
`$("#partA.myClass").size()`
I get `0`. 
Apparently, that javascript command only looks for elements that have both `id=partA` and `class=myClass`.
Is it possible to reformulate that command in order to count the number of `myClass` class that are contained within the elements with `id=partA`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Consider reading a basic jQuery tutorial as well as the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a space in one of your selectors. Try:

```
$("#partA .myClass").size()
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
$('#partA').find('.myClass').length;
```

Or

```
var partA = $('#partA');
$('.myClass', partA).length;
```

Comment: oh! right! just like CSS! how dumb of me! (feel ashamed) Thanks a lot, it works :D. (Will accept it after the min time is over)

Comment: `size()` is deprecated...use `length`